# Full-Flexible button in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to understand and struggle with the bootstrap grid.

I would need to build a group of button like this:

[image]

All buttons stretch to each box width and height.

However when the button has more text, the button starts to wrap/creates new line and the close button is not aligned with the above column:
[image]

The following is my code :

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
            <div class="row gy-5">
                <div class="col p-2 border border-1">
                    <button class="btn-danger">Button Row 1</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col p-2 border border-1">
                    <button class="btn-danger">Button Row 1</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col p-2 border border-1">
                    <button class="btn-danger">Button Row 1</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col p-2 border border-1">
                    <button class="btn-danger">Button Row 2</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col p-2 border border-1">
                    <button class="btn-danger">Button Row 2</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col p-2 border border-1">
                    <button class="btn-danger">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col p-2 border border-1">
                        <button>Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Kindly please to advise to have the button filled the each box with padding, and all boxes should have the same height/width follows the largest button size

Comment: I think all of your rows need to be in the same container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code produces the exact layout you want:

```css
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column" style="width: fit-content">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="p-2 border border-1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Button Row 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 border border-1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Button Row 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 border border-1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Button Row 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="p-2 border border-1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Button Row 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 border border-1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Button Row 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 border border-1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Button Row 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex align-self-center">
    <div class="p-2 border border-1">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```